# Numerical solution for ODE using NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE:

```
y'[z]==-(y[z]^2-x[z]^2) chi/z^2
```

with the initial condition

```
y[z0] == x[z0]
```

where

```
x[z_] := -0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) - 0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) + 0.43999 E^(-0.965985 z);
chi = 5.5 10^12;
z0 = 20;
```

I know that the solution, i.e., y(z) should look like:
[image]

But instead of this, I got the next solution with Wolfram Mathematica (WM) using NDSolve:

[image]

My WM code is:

```
x[z_] := -0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) - 0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) + 
   0.43999 E^(-0.965985 z);
chi = 5.5 10^12;
z0 = 20;
solution = 
  NDSolve[{ y'[z] == -(y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2, y[z0] == x[z0]}, 
   y, {z, 10, 100}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
LogLogPlot[{Legended[Evaluate[y[z] /. solution], 
   Placed[StyleForm["y", FontSize -> 12], {.7, .8}]], 
  Legended[x[z], 
   Placed[StyleForm["x", FontSize -> 12], {.7, .8}]]}, {z, 100/7, 
  100}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.004], Red}, {Thickness[.004], 
    Dashed, Purple}}, FrameLabel -> {"z", "y, x"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.95, 
 PlotRange -> {{100/7, 100}, {0.2 10^-11, 4 10^-7}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 
  Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, FontColor -> Black], 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, FontColor -> Black], 
 AspectRatio -> 0.95]
```

I do not understand why my solution is getting unstable.  Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: You have either not defined `yxeq[z]` as a function or you've meant to do something different than you do do.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, yxeq[z] - > x[z]. I have already corrected this. The basic problem is the correct integration of the ODE. The correct solution is shown in the first picture I included to this question, but I cannot reproduce it in WM.

Comment: Adding `AccuracyGoal -> 100` to `NDSolve` improves y for z>20

Comment: Thank You! It works! I have to set also z0 = 14 and I got a solution which reasonably well agrees with the correct one.

Comment: I think @MelaGo has a good suggestion, since one probably wants the `AccuracyGoal` at (64-bit) machine precision to be at least eight digits more than, say, the "average" value of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating a number of comments, just so the question has an answer...

```
x[z_] := -0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) - 0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) + 
   0.43999 E^(-0.965985 z);
chi = 5.5 10^12;
z0 = 14;

solution = 
  NDSolve[{y'[z] == -(y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2, y[z0] == x[z0]}, 
   y, {z, 10, 100}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 100];

LogLogPlot[{Legended[Evaluate[y[z] /. solution], 
   Placed[StyleForm["y", FontSize -> 12], {.7, .8}]], 
  Legended[x[z], 
   Placed[StyleForm["x", FontSize -> 12], {.7, .8}]]}, {z, 100/7, 
  100}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[.004], Red}, {Thickness[.004], 
    Dashed, Purple}}, FrameLabel -> {"z", "y, x"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.95, 
 PlotRange -> {{100/7, 100}, {0.2 10^-11, 4 10^-7}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> 
  Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, FontColor -> Black], 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[FontSize -> 12, FontWeight -> Plain, FontColor -> Black], 
 AspectRatio -> 0.95]
```

[image]

Comment: y(z) and x(z) must agree in the region 14<z<20, and then y(z) should smoothly separate from x(z) as shown in the first picture I included to this question.

Answer (score 5):

*Update: Incorporating comments*

Originally I took for granted that the expected result was correct.  A quick look at the IVP shows it starts on the nullcline $y(z)=x(z)$:
$$
y'(z)=-\frac{\chi\cdot\left(y(z)^2-x(z)^2\right)}{z^2}, \quad y(z_0)=x(z_0) \,.
$$
Since $y'(x)$ changes sign and $\chi$ is large, the quick reversal at $z=z_0$ should be expected.

The waviness to the right of $z=z_0=20$ in the OP is a numerical issue, but the issue is not stability.  The default `AccuracyGoal` is around `8`.  Given an accuracy goal $a$, error estimates less than around $10^{-a}$ are accepted.  When the magnitude of the solution is not much more or less than $10^{-a}$, then errors are accepted that are significantly large relative to the solution.  I think of the accuracy goal as telling `NDSolve` the largest number that I would consider equivalent to zero.  If it produces jittery noise that the user finds unacceptable, the user should increase `AccuracyGoal`.  In this case, since the first run produced a solution that spends a lot of time around $10^{-11}$, one should expect to need an `AccuracyGoal` of around `19` or `20` to get single-precision results.

So two modifications are needed:  Change the location of the initial condition to be to the left of the integration interval, and increase the `AccuracyGoal`.

However, being interested in the mathematical problem, I tried to see how close I could get to `x[t]`.  We can do pretty well if we start at the maximum of `x[t]`.  Since both `y'[t]` and `x'[t]` at this point, this is probably the best we can do; at all other initial conditions on the graph of `x[t]`, the solution will cross the graph.  The following does a good job until `y[z]` tries to change sign:

```
x[z_] = Rationalize[-0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) - 
    0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) + 0.43999 E^(-0.965985 z), 10^-6/2];
chi = 55/10*10^12;
z0 = z /. First@NSolve[x'[z] == 0 && 0 < z < 5, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
solution = NDSolve[
  {y'[z] == -(y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2, y[z0] == x[z0]},
  y, {z, 0, 100},
  AccuracyGoal -> 20,
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
    "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

> NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at z == 1.1604817342549352`; unable to continue.

Changing variables $t=e^z$ and using the method `"StiffnessSwitching"`, we can integrate further into `y[z] < 0`, but the integrator struggles when `z < 0.7`. The left edge of the plot below represents noise and not the true solution.  A log plot is not possible because the solution changes sign, so I scaled the `y` coordinate by the varying factor `Exp[z/2]`.  Exponential grid lines are shown with the scale indicated on top.  The separation of `y` from `x` shows `y[z]` approaching $\approx 5.15 \times 10^{-12}$ as $z \rightarrow +\infty$.

```
z0 = z /. First@NSolve[x'[z] == 0 && 0 < z < 5, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
solution = 
 NDSolve[{Exp[-t] y'[t] == -(y[t]^2 - x[Exp[t]]^2) chi/Exp[t]^2, 
   y[Log@z0] == x[z0]}, y, {t, -Log@100, Log@100},
  AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10,
  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &, 
    "WarningMessage" -> False}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]

Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[Exp[z/2] Join[
     Table[10^y0/Exp[1/2], {y0, -12, -3}]]],
  {z, 0, 43},
  PlotStyle -> Join[
    Table[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[0.5], Gray], {y0, -12, -3}]],
  PlotRange -> {-0.015, 0.015}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 
     Table[{1 - 2 (2 + y0) Log[10], 10.^y0}, {y0, -12, -3, 2}]}}],
 Plot[Evaluate[Exp[z/2] Join[
     {y[Log@z] /. solution, x[z]}]],
  {z, 0, 42},
  PlotStyle -> Join[
    {AbsoluteThickness[3], AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}],
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> {y, x}]
 ]
```

> [image]

It should be clear that the desired plot is somewhat misleading. On the one hand, the IC `y[z0] == x[z0]` always results in a solution that goes down to the left as in the OP. On the other, the plot makes it look like `y[z]` and `x[z]` are asymptotic to each other (or even that they agree) as `z` decreases toward zero.

*Original answer*

I <s>think it's</s> *thought it was* just numerical instability. [The analysis below the graph shows why the OP's plot should have a quick turn at the initial condition.]  I had to change the `y` variable to $y = 10^{u/10}$, because `StreamPlot` is finicky and needs a plot range that is roughly square.

```
changeVar = y -> (10^(u[#]/10) &);
First@*Solve @@@ (
     NestList[
      D[#, z] /. First@Solve[First@#, u'[z]] &,
      {y'[z] == -(y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2 /. changeVar, u'[z]}, 1]
     ) /. u[z] -> u // Flatten;
MapThread[Set[#[u_, z_], #2] &, {{up, upp}, {u'[z], u''[z]} /. %}];
?up
?upp

Show[
 ContourPlot[
  {up[u, z] == 0, upp[u, z] == 0},
  {z, 15, 40}, {u, -115, -90},
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Dashed, Darker@Green], 
    Directive[Dashed, Darker@Magenta]},
  FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{10 # &, #/10 &}], 
     Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  PlotLegends -> {u'[z] == 0, u''[z] == 0}
  ],
 StreamPlot[
  {1, up[u, z]},
  {z, 15, 40}, {u, -115, -90},
  StreamPoints -> {{{sepIC + 0.033, Red}, Automatic}}]
 ]
```

> [image]

Moving to the left, if a solution steps across the green line `u'[z] == 0`, the solution heads down.  Step across the purple line `u''[z] == 0` and the solution becomes concave down and it will eventually step across the green line.

Comment: I would add that there are clearly solutions that cross `u''[z] == 0` and solutions that do not.  The boundary between these must also be a solution that does not cross `u''[z] == 0`.

Comment: Another remark: I didn't pay attention to the ODE. It turns out that `u'[z] == 0` is equivalent to `y'[z] == 0` and `y[z] == x[z]`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Setting z0 = 14 and adding AccuracyGoal -> 100 finally solved my problem.

Comment: @student You're welcome.  One more remark: The IC `y[z0] == x[z0]` sets the starting value for `y` to be the turning point (maximum) of the solution. Since you plot only from `100/7` = `14.2857`, you do no see it turn down at `z == 14`.  So it's a good choice for approximating the solution you seek.  Perhaps even better is `z0 = 10` or `9`, since you're integrating from `10` to `100`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very impressive idea! Using this transformation `y->u` , `NDSolve` is able to solve this problem without assumptions `AccuracyGoal ->…, Method->…` !

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be solved without additional assumptions `AccuracyGoal->…`and `Method->…` using the transformation `y[z]->10^u[z]` which @MichaelE2 (Thanks for the idea!) showed in his very interesting answer:

```
x[z_] := -0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) - 0.226679 E^(-0.991987 z) + 0.43999 E^(-0.965985 z);
z0=10;
chi = 5.5 10^12;

changeVar = y -> (  10^(u[#]/10) &);(**)
```

transformed ode:

```
odeu = (-y'[z] - (y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2)     /. changeVar
```

new boundary condition:

```
uz0 = u[z0] /. Solve[y[z0] == x[z0] /. changeVar, u[z0]][[1]]
```

->ready to solve

```
U = NDSolveValue[{odeu == 0, u[z0] == uz0}, u, {z, 10, 100}]
```

plot of `y[z]= 10^(U[z]/10)`

```
LogLogPlot[   10^(U[z]/10)  , {z, z0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your other comment. For me, I think `z0 = 10;
solution = NDSolve[{y'[z] == -(y[z]^2 - x[z]^2) chi/z^2, y[z0] == x[z0]}, y, {z, 10, 100}, AccuracyGoal -> 20]` is the simplest approach. (As I mentioned [in another comment](), the goal of `20` is suggested by `-Log10[Quartiles[y[Subdivide[10., 100., 100]] /. First@solution]] + 8.`, which can be easily seen from the plot, too. (+1)

Comment: Thanks. That's true, but you have to know the solution.

Comment: Yep, but from a test solution, you get a hint about `AccuracyGoal`. In this case, the OP knew the theoretical asymptotic limit around `5 * 10^-12`, which suggests `AccuracyGoal -> 20`; even if it was unknown, the initial condition `x[20.] = 7 * 10^-10` is known.